# PlugIn function implementation with C#

Tags: c#, reflection, plugins

I need to call a function to call user's dll in C#.

For example, when user makes a abc.dll with class ABC, I want to load the dll to run the methods xyz(a) in the class.

```
object plugInObject = node.GetPlugInObject("abc.dll", "ABC");
plugInObject.runMethod("xyz", "a");
```

How can I implement those functions in C#?

### ADDED

This is plugin code, and the dll is copied as plugin/plugin.dll.

```
namespace HIR
{
    public class PlugIn
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return (x + y);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the one that calls this plugin.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class UsePlugIn
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile("./plugin/plugin.dll");
        Type plugInType = asm.GetType("HIR.PlugIn");
        Object plugInObj = Activator.CreateInstance(plugInType);

        var res = plugInType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(plugInObj, new Object[] { 10, 20 });
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: read about **reflection**, dynamic dll loading

Comment: Are those *.dll files .NET assemblies or native libraries?

Comment: According to plugin implementation there is no method "Abc" which you used along with GetMethod().

Comment: PlugIn class should be public. Without modifier it is claimed to be internal by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be translated in C# and .NET to the following:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile("ABC.dll");
Type plugInType = asm.GetType("ABC");
Object plugInObj = Activator.CreateInstance(plugInType);

plugInType.GetMethod("xyz").Invoke(plugInObj, new Object[] { "a" });
```

It is called `Reflection`.

Comment: it is called "Reflection", cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

```
* Declare the method with the static and extern C# keywords.
* Attach the DllImport attribute to the method. The DllImport attribute allows you to specify the name of the DLL that contains the method. The common practice is to name the C# method the same as the exported method, but you can also use a different name for the C# method.
* Optionally, specify custom marshaling information for the method's parameters and return value, which will override the .NET Framework default marshaling.

//Example of how to use methods from User32.dll
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
```

[see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#pinvoke_callingdllexport) for more details